# Populating an existing listview in a viewpager

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I am working on a project where i have 3 activities/fragments in a viewpager

now i want to populate this listview hardcoded or a JSON file, problem is that findviewbyid returns a null so i can't add any new items.

i Use this pageradapter to create the viewpager

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        int resId = 0;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                resId = R.layout.activity_friend;
                break;
            case 1:
                resId = R.layout.activity_mainactiv;
                break;
            case 2:
                resId = R.layout.activity_map;
                break;
        }
        View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }

    //public boolean isViewFromObject(ViewGroup arg0, Object arg1) {
    // return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    //}
    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The pages inside can de fragments or activity haven't decided yet what's best for my app

Then here is the main where the viewpager is located

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager_layout"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

i've read some tutorials and i know you have to populate the listview in the mainactivity oncreate or in the pageradapter where you inflate your pages

```
prepareListData();
listDataHeader.toArray(Listdata);
ListView listview1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
ArrayAdapter<String> Sadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Listdata);
listview1.setAdapter(Sadapter);
```

This is the code i tried to use to populate the listview

i hope i can get some more info here so i know where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured it out,

```
resId = R.layout.activity_mainactiv;
                    v = inflater.inflate(resId,null);

                    // get the listview
                    View explist = v.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView2);
                    expListView = (ExpandableListView)explist;

                    // preparing list data
                    prepareListData();
```

you make a new view out of the inflated one and you make sure the list is in it,and then i populated it using a method i created